# Adding a high score to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to add a high score to my game. Right now I have this:

```
var score = 0;
var highscore = 0;
```

The score variable works but whenever I get like points so total of 60 points it says the high score is still zero when checking it using `console.log(highscore)`.

I have this to store the high score:

```
if (score > localStorage.getItem("highscore")) {
  localStorage.setItem("highscore", score);
}
```

This does not work properly, but it also doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Just a thought to your pastebin, you might want to convert your variables to objects, would help a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var score = 0;
var highscore = localStorage.getItem("highscore");

if(highscore !== null){
    if (score > highscore) {
        localStorage.setItem("highscore", score);      
    }
}
else{
    localStorage.setItem("highscore", score);
}
```

Comment: No, localStorage stores strings!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `parseInt`, you need to set the init value on the `localStorage` first because `localStorage.getItem("highscore",10)` doesn't returns 10 as default value if is not setted

```
var score = 0;
var highscore = 0;
localStorage.setItem("highscore",0);
```

Because when you check

```
if (score > parseInt(localStorage.getItem("highscore"))) {
  localStorage.setItem("highscore", score);
}
```

The  `localStorage.getItem("highscore")` will return null if the item is not setted yet. Or you can also do:

```
var storagedHighScore = localStorage.getItem("highscore");
if (storagedHighScore  || score > parseInt(storagedHighScore)) {
  localStorage.setItem("highscore", score);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the value from localStorage with

```
highscore = +localStorage.getItem("highscore")
```

or some equivalent code.  Items in `localStorage` don't track the global variables with the same names.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (score > parseInt(localStorage.getItem('highscore'), 10)) {
  localStorage.setItem('highscore', score);
}
```

convert into int before comparing. its string

Comment: still doesnt work unfortanalty you can watch my hole code here http://pastebin.com/sgZS8tzz

Comment: can you share jsfiddle or plnkr link. i cant access pastebin

Comment: it a hole game this is one script but yeah i can putt it in jsfiddle 
here you go
http://jsfiddle.net/unb8yLj3/

Comment: This should not matter, as it should be coerced to a number if `score` is a number.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy :- My Bad. You are right. it will convert automatically.

Comment: @superman :- where are you setting score variable. The only place i see is initialization the score variable to 0.

Answer (score -1):

I just reviewed your code in http://jsfiddle.net/unb8yLj3/ and i couldn't find in what part you increase the score so when this part of code run score is 0 and 
localStorage.getItem("highscore") is 10 therefore it doesn't set highscore.

```
if (score > localStorage.getItem("highscore")) {
                localStorage.setItem("highscore", score);

            }

  }
```

Is there another js file that does increase the score?