# Learn to use localstorage in JS

Tags: javascript, local-storage

**Hey**

I would like to save and display a value called "bestScore"

I have looked on the internet I can see examples far from my situation

**I would like to know how to store and display a value**

**If anyone has a very simple and easy example**

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried looking this up online? There are many tutorials on localStorage that can be found quite easily.

Comment: ```localStorage.getItem()``` and ```localStorage.setItem()```. I doubt you couldn't find examples to demonstrate the absolute basics of ```LocalStorage```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370629/5459839) in linked duplicate reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
//store the value
localStorage.setItem("bestScore", 'here put the score');

//get the value
localStorage.getItem("bestScore");

//you can write it as a function
function saveScore(score){
 localStorage.setItem("bestScore", score);
}

function getScore(scoreName){
 localStorage.getItem(scoreName);
}

//then you can call the function and pass arguments for example
let scoreElement = document.getElementById('score').innerText
saveScore(scoreElement) //call the save function and pass the score to save

scoreElement = getScore('bestScore') //call the get score function and pass the name of the item in the storage
```