# How do I add a high score counter to my vanilla JavaScript game?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Looking to make a high score keeper that displays only the highest score for my game.

I have been able to add a score counter but I'm not sure how to check and add the highscore at the end of each round. Ive looked here and know it has to do with adding and retrieving from the local storage but I was having a difficult time implementing it to my app.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Poseyv12/pen/poKpgxX)

This is my JavaScript:

```
point = 0
const high = document.querySelector("#highScore")                                                              
const myScore = document.querySelector("#score")
const playBtn = document.querySelector("h2");
const resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset")
const target = document.querySelector(".target");
const gameSpace = document.querySelector("#playSpace")
const music = new Audio("music/DNB.mp3")
const targetHit = new Audio('music/pop.wav')
const move = new Audio('music/move.wav');
const click = new Audio('music/click.mp3')
const shot = new Audio('music/Shot.mp3')
const gameOver = new Audio('music/gameOver.wav')

target.hidden = true

let volume = document.querySelector("#volume-control"); // volume control
volume.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    music.volume = e.currentTarget.value / 100;
})

gameSpace.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    shot.play()
    shot.currentTime = 0;
})

window.onclick = function () {
    myScore.innerText = "MY SCORE = " + point;
}

target.addEventListener("click", function (e) {     // target click events
    targetHit.play()
    targetHit.volume = .05
    targetHit.currentTime = 0;
    point++;
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800)
    const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800)
    const newPosition = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
    target.style.transform = newPosition
    target.style.transition = ".1s"
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    const newColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    // console.log(point)
})

function startTimer(duration, display) {  // timer function
    let timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    function gameEnd() {
        timer = 0;
        gameOver.loop = false;
        gameOver.play()
        target.hidden = true;
        clearInterval(interval)
        music.pause();
        music.currentTime = 0;
        point = 0
    }

    let interval = setInterval(function () {

        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        if (--timer < 0) {
            gameEnd()
        }

    }, 1000);
}

playBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {  // play
    target.hidden = false
    let play = false;
    if (play == false) {
        music.play()
        click.play()
        music.loop = true
        console.log("click")
        play = true
        var fiveMinutes = 60 * 1,                                        // start timer
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    }
})

let slider = document.querySelector('.size')

slider.addEventListener('input', e => {
    target.style.width = e.target.value + 'px'
    target.style.height = e.target.value + 'px'
})

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    location.reload()
})
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="heading"> Target Practice v1 </div>
    <h2 id="play"> CLICK TO PLAY</h2>            
    <div id="reset"> Reset</div>

    <!-- Game play area -->
    <div id="playSpace">
        <span id="highScore"> High Score = 0</span>
        <span class="timer">Timer: <span id="time">01:00</span>
        </span>
        <span id="score">
            my SCORE = 0
        </span>
        <div>
            <button class="target">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--lables and sliders -->
    <div id="settings">                                            
        <label id="volLable"> Music Volume</label>
        <input class="volume" type="range" id="volume-control">
        <h3 id="sizeLable"> Target Size </h3>
        <input class="size" type='range' min="30" max="150" value="100">
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `localStorage` :)

Comment: There are [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20localstorage%20score) of similar questions, but this one seems simple to follow: [Adding a high score to local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370017/adding-a-high-score-to-local-storage)